# Is using an infinite timer/interval to simulate a modal dialog a good idea?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, setinterval

As modal dialogs are not supported in FF/chrome, I’m thinking about implementing an infinite loop, which will be aborted by a ok/cancel button in the displayed div with screen overlay. Is this a good idea? What pitfalls I should avoid? Memory overflows? Will I block/slow down any other tabs? Is this generally a good idea or should I look elsewhere?

Comment: *modal dialogs are not supported in FF/chrome*, what do you mean not supported? Are you talking about a certain element or function? *I’m thinking about implementing an infinite loop*, to do what? JavaScript is event-driven, so why would you need an infinite loop? Though questions regarding advice will surely be closed, I'm curious what you're referring at and what the context is of your question.

Comment: What I’m trying to simulate is a window.showModalDialog(…). This is not supported in FF/Chrome. The purpose is that on submit if a form there are a lot of checks and user input required. On submit I fire a function and before I submit at the end, I need input from the user, so the execution of the function needs to halt and wait for user input. This I would like to emulate with displaying an overlay div, starting an infinite loop and when the user hits ok on the overlay, stop the loop and continue with processing the function. I hope this clears out the purpose

Comment: Ah I see. To answer your question then: the loop is a bad idea. If your code needs an infinite loop for waiting to proceed then your code is bad. It will prevent any other code from running and will ruin your website. The part of showing the div as modal is a common used pattern. But in the modal, listen for a click on the button. When the user clicks, call a function which will process the information and continue the flow. For an example, look for Bootstrap Modal.